# NSPredicate filter array with first character

Tags: ios, swift, filter, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter an array with the first letter of name

I'm using this :

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name beginswith[c] %@", sections.objectAtIndex(section) as! String)
    let sectionArray = self.mContacts.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

Where section is :

```
let sections = NSArray(objects: "#","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")
```

# must contain all the name begin by a digit.

But I can not filter the name begin by digit with this method.

I'm looking for some advices, thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this with MATCHES[c]

```
for sectionLetter in sections {
        if (sectionLetter as! String) == "#" {
            let predicateFormat = NSString(format: "name MATCHES[c] '[0-9].*'")
            let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:predicateFormat as String)

            let sectionArray = self.mContacts.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
            mSectionArray.addObject(sectionArray)
        } else {
            let predicateFormat = NSString(format: "name MATCHES[c] '(%@).*'", sectionLetter as! String)
            let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:predicateFormat as String)

            let sectionArray = self.mContacts.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
            mSectionArray.addObject(sectionArray)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me :)